# .Net Core 206 partial content error on mobile network

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, http-headers, html5-video, filestream

I have a client that streams videos from the client-backend and an api.

On the Client-backend, the video stream fails over mobile network sometimes, this never occurs with the api.

(.net core v2.0)
Here is my file stream on the client back-end (now replaced with v2.1):

```
[HttpGet("ConvertedVideo/{path}")]
public FileStreamResult ConvertedVideo(string path)
{
    return FileStreamResult(_fileManager.ConvertedStream(path), "video/mp4");
}
```

Also I have enabled range processing in my `Program.cs` with
`AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EnableRangeProcessing", true);`

After updating to (.net core v2.1) still the same issue:

```
[HttpGet("ConvertedVideo/{path}")]
public FileStreamResult ConvertedVideo(string path)
{
    var stream = _fileManager.ConvertedStream(path);

    return File(stream, "video/mp4", path, true);
}
```

Both of these works fine, this method returns success 206, and then a few following calls are made (1-3) depending on the size of the video.

Both of these don't work on my mobile when it's using mobile network, over wifi it's fine.

Here is the Request Headers (other headers omitted for clarity):

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Range: bytes=0-
```

Here is the Response Header:

```
Accept-Ranges: none
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1247369
Content-Range: bytes 0-1247368/1247369
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Sun, 22 Jul 2018 16:27:13 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Here is what the error looks like in the console:

`GET http://example.com/ConvertedVideo/video.mp4 206 (Partial Content)`

In the Network tab:

`net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`

I don't understand why it's not working on mobile network? Is it breaking because it's partial content?

**Edit:** Before the video is streamed on the client it is converted to lower quality using `ffmpeg` wrapper: `MediaToolKit`. I suspect this could be part of the issue but why would it work on wifi and not mobile network? After the same video is sent to the api and is streamed from there, and works fine both over wifi and mobile.

Both the api and client are hosted on an IIS shared hosting platform.

PS: It's a dynamically created `html5-video` container and the `src` is also generated dynamically and is loaded with vuejs, I had suspicions this might be the cause, but I don't understand why it would work on wifi but not mobile network.

**Edit:**

Updated the client project to 2.1, still the same issue.

<strike>This issue doesn't occur on IPhones.</strike>  <strike>It does.</strike> It works on Iphones more than it doesn't work.

Api video streaming that works on the client:

```
[HttpGet("matchvid/{id}/{path}")]
public FileStreamResult Get(string id, string path)
{
    return new FileStreamResult(_fileManager.VideoStream(id, path), "video/mp4");
}
```

This is how I read the file (changing to `Path.Combine(type, name)` doesn't solve the issue.):

```
private FileStream VideoStream(string type, string name)
{
    var fileStream = new FileStream($"{type}/{name}",
              FileMode.Open,
              FileAccess.Read);

    return fileStream;
}
```

**Other things I tried**

- I have read somewhere this might be a firewall issue, I contacted my hosting providers, they confirmed it's not.
- setting the header `Accept-Ranges: "bytes"` manually in the streaming method, thorough filters, custom middleware.

**Edit: Testing issue on Firefox Mobile Browser:**

1st request/response is identical to the one that fails. (The streams that work do not start with Accept-Ranges: "none")

But then FF makes a second request/response (this doesn't occur in chrome).

Request:

```
Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q…q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language:    en-GB,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Range:  bytes=8904-
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges:  bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition:    attachment; filename=received_…received_1416546955092120.mp4
Content-Length: 1330243
Content-Range:  bytes 8904-1339146/1339147
Content-Type:   video/mp4
```

**Here is the error that follows** (`src` expects `video/mp4`, File stream returns `video/mp4` and the file is `mp4` format.)

`Media resource <url> could not be decoded.`

`All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.`

`Media resource <url> could not be decoded, error: Error Code:(0x806e0006) Details: static MP4Metadata::ResultAndByteBuffer mozilla::MP4Metadata::Metadata(mozilla::ByteStream *): Cannot parse metadata`

So now I have ether an encoding error or partial content error.

Comment: You should use Wireshark to capture the TCP conversation and examine the data. The ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH advises that the actual payload sent does not match the headers, maybe the connection is being terminated.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I will look in to it